# Selecting specific dates from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with the column 'Date', which has dates in several formats, including:

- 2018.05.07
- 01-Jun-2018
- Reported 01 Jun 2018
- Jun 2018
- 2018
- before 1970
- 1941-1945
- Ca. 1960

There are also invalid dates, such as:

- 190Feb-2010

I am trying to find dates which have an exact date (day, month, and year) and convert them to datetime. I also need to exclude dates with "Reported" in the field. Is there any way to filter such data without finding before all the possible formats of dates?

Comment: So you will either have to filter out the bad entries or filter out the good ones. I don't know how big you dataset is, but I would suggest to start with filtering out the entries which cannot be handled by `to_datatime`. Your question is too broad to be answered here though.

Comment: "2018" can be handled by `to_datetime`, but i don't need such dates. Guess it would be better to find good ones, but how can i be sure? :) there're about 6k rows

Answer (score 1):

Using dateutil library.

if statement to check if any part of date (month,year,date) is missing, if yes then avoid it.

use `fuzzy=True` if want to extract dates from strings such as "Reported 01 Jun 2018"

```
    import dateutil.parser
    dates = ["2018.05.07","01-Jun-2018","Reported 01 Jun 2018","Jun 2018","2018","before 1970","1941-1945","Ca. 1960","190Feb-2010"]
    formated_date = []
    for date in dates:
        try:
            if dateutil.parser.parse(date,fuzzy=False,default=datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)) == dateutil.parser.parse(date,fuzzy=False,default=datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 2)):
                formated_date.append(yourdate)
        except:
            continue
```

another solution. This is brute force method that check each date with every format. Keep on adding more formats to make it work on any date format. But this is time taking method.

```
import datetime

dates = ["2018.05.07","01-Jun-2018","Reported 01 Jun 2018","Jun 2018","2018","before 1970","1941-1945","Ca. 1960","190Feb-2010"]

formats = ["%Y%m%d","%Y.%m.%d","%Y-%m-%d","%Y/%m/%d","%Y%a%d","%Y.%a.%d","%Y-%a-%d","%Y%A%d","%Y.%A.%d","%Y-%A-%d",
          "%d-%m-%Y","%d.%m.%Y","%d%m%Y","%d/%m/%Y","%d-%b-%Y","%d%b%Y","%d.%b.%Y","%d/%b/%Y"]

formated_date = []
for date in dates:
    for fmt in formats:
        try:
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,fmt)
            formated_date.append(dt)
        except:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: string_with_dates = """entries are due by January 4th, 2017 at 8:00pm created 01/15/2005 by ACME Inc. and associates."""

In [2]: import datefinder

In [3]: matches = datefinder.find_dates(string_with_dates)

In [4]: for match in matches:
   ...:     print match


2017-01-04 20:00:00
2005-01-15 00:00:00
```

Hope this would help you to find dates from string with dates